# a basic require system with bash and sed: substitute for the contents of a file

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, include

I would like to use sed to find something like `#<file.sh>`, and replace that line with the contents of file.sh.

The closest I got was

```
echo "#<file.sh>" | sed "s/\#<\(.*\)>/\1/"
```

And that replaces `#<file.sh>` for `file.sh`. I would now like to replace it for the contents of the file, instead of the filename I found.

I tried then

```
echo "#<file.sh>" | sed "s/\#<\(.*\)>/$(cat \1)/"
```

But that ends up saying `cat: 1: inexisting file or directory`, so it's trying to read \1 instead of the file.sh, which I saved in \1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `GNU sed`, the following might work for you:

```
sed '/#<\(.*\)>/s|.*|cat \1|e' filename
```

---

Example:

```
$ cat foo 
abc
#</tmp/o/a.c>
def
$ cat /tmp/o/a.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
}
$ sed 's|#<\(.*\)>|cat \1|e' foo
abc
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
}
def
```

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo Yes.  If you're using `GNU sed`, it __should__.

Comment: I think I should be, I'm in an ubuntu box... I got this: sed: -e expression #1, character 24: reference \1 invalid in RHS of command 's'

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo Are you certain that you don't have a typo?

Comment: @JoãoPintoJerónimo I've added an example to demonstrate it works!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @devnull's answer, try the following:

```
sed '/\#<.*>/s|#<\(.*\)>|cat \1|e' filename
```

On my system the back-reference has to be in the search part of the search and replace.  You also need to avoid the #<> that you collected at the beginning.